# Use of ffmpeg and ffprobe exe files in application

Tags: lgpl, ffmpeg

We have written very small application in Visual Studio which uses 2 x FFmpeg commands and 1 x FFprobe command. We plan to include the two exe files as a resource when the application is packaged in an installer MSI file.
FFMPEG we use the “filter” command
FFMPEG to convert MP4 videos to AVI
FFProbe we use to get the video resolution
I have read https://ffmpeg.org/legal.html information and I would like to check if the 3 commands we are using above are covered under the  GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 2.1 or later.
Thank you for your help :)